# Cómo utilizar un ciclo for para optimizar código en Python con PyQt5

Tags: python

Estoy comenzando en python y agradezco si pudieran ayudarme.

Como parte de mi programa he diseñado un formulario en PyQt5 que contiene 5 QLineEdit, los mismos son rellenados a partir de las siguientes líneas de código:

```
self.le_cod_don.setText(res_cons_sel[0][0])
self.le_nomb_don.setText(res_cons_sel[0][1])
self.le_pais_don.setText(res_cons_sel[0][2])
self.le_resp_don.setText(res_cons_sel[0][3])
self.le_email_don.setText(res_cons_sel[0][4])
```

Estas líneas se obtienen a partir de dos listas:

La primera:

```
self.controles = [self.le_cod_don, self.le_nomb_don, self.le_pais_don, self.le_resp_don, self.le_email_don]
```

y la segunda, que a su vez contiene una tupla:

```
res_cons_sel = [('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')]
```

He tratado de simplificar las líneas de código mediante una iteración con el ciclo `for` pero a lo máximo que he llegado es a que me rellene todos los QLineEdit con la tupla completa de la segunda lista en cada uno. No he logrado obtener por separado cada índice de la tupla contenida dentro de la lista res_cons_sel.

Mi ciclo anidado es:

```
        for wdg in self.controles:
            for res in range(0,len(res_cons_sel)):
                wdg.setText(str(res_cons_sel[res]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tienes que anidar dos `for` para hacer la asignación que quieres, más bien tienes que hacer un solo ciclo for donde tengas accesibles los elementos de la lista y la tupla, por ejemplo:

```
for i in range(len(res_cons_sel[0])):
  controles[i|.setText(str(res_cons_sel[0][i]))
```

Si repasas tu programa original, verás como a cada edit le vas asignando todos los valores de la lista de tuplas, por lo que, al final, todos los edits se quedarán con el último valor de esta lista.

Dicho esto, no comprendo por qué defines la variable `res_cons_sel` con una lista de tuplas, al menos en el código que muestras, sería más simple tener una sola tupla, o una lista de cadenas, por ejemplo:

```
res_cons_sel = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
for i in range(len(res_cons_sel)):
  controles[i|.setText(res_cons_sel[i])
```

Comment: La lista de tuplas res_cons_sel se obtiene a partir de una consulta a una base de datos SQLite. Cuando corro la solución aportada obtengo como error: ----Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Programacion/ProyObi/venv/main.py", line 116, in seleccion_donante
    self.controles[i].setText(str(res_cons_sel[0][i]))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'setText'------------------------------------¿Debo convertir la lista de tuplas en una lista de cadenas?¿Cómo lo haría? Gracias

Comment: Lo que ese error está diciendo es que en la lista controles tienes `strings`, y no los widgets de QT. Es decir, no la construyes como mostraste en la pregunta. Y ciertamente, los strings no tienen un método `setText`.

Comment: Realmente no tengo strings, de hecho lo conseguí a partir de tu aporte, pero recorriendo la primera lista en lugar de la segunda, o sea, recorro primero los controles y luego asigno el resultado de la consulta. Agradezco mucho tu solución, al final pude conseguir el objetivo. ------------------------------            for i in range(len(self.controles)):
     self.controles[i].setText(str(res_cons_sel[0][i]))

Comment: Ariel, había un error en el código del ejemplo, era más o menos trivial, pero si has captado la idea y lo has podido adaptar usando la otra lista, lo importante es que ha quedado. Un saludo.